# How to display integers with pattern using loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to display the integer like

```
1111
222
33
4
```

using loop but i dont know what is wrong with my code, i'm new to c programming and thanks for your help :D
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    for (int a=4; a<=1; a--) 
    {
        for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
        printf("%d", b);
        }
    } 
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If the loop starts with `a=4` and loops while a is smaller than one it will obviously never start

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: @klutt ya just realised that sry im new

Comment: @Mystheman the output will just be black and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    for (int a=4; a<=1; a--) /* a<=1 is false when a=4 */
    {
        for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
        printf("%d", b); /* what is printed depends on b while it shouldn't */
        }
    } 
    printf("\n"); /* this is in wrong place */
}
```

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    for (int a=4; a>=1; a--)
    {
        for (int b=1; b<=a; b++) {
            printf("%d", 1 + (4 - a));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio [The output is just like expected](https://wandbox.org/permlink/px3HwxXeqWetd802) and loops are used. What other things are required?

Comment: OK. Yes, I see now. But still the redundant variable declaration remain.

Answer (score 0):

First, the condition in the first loop "a<=1" will never be true since you are initializing a=4.

Comment: no problem, maybe try to use while loops first to understand better the inicialization and how the condition of the loop works.

Comment: This only solves *one* issue. A lot of others remain.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has four issues.

#### 1.

You declare `a` and `b` twice. One time before and one time inside of the loops. The ones you use are actually the variables you declare/define inside of the loop's initialization parts. The variables `a` and `b` declared outside are completely redundant and unused in your actual code.

#### 2.

The condition of the outer `for` loop `a <= 1` will never be true and you will not at least go one time through the loops because `a` is initialized with `4` and since `4` is not less or equal than `1` you will have no iteration at all.

The condition needs to be `a >= 1`, not `a <= 1`.

#### 3.

`printf("\n");` needs to be placed inside of the outer loop and not outside of it.

#### 4.

The logic of your inner `for` loop is flaw. We need a counter inside of the inner loop and test it against a condition instead to use and increment `b`. Doing so would gives you only numbers in ascending order in each line.

Increment `b` after the inner loop is complete.

---

Corrected code ([Online test](https://godbolt.org/z/vz7adr)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int a = 4, b = 1;

    for ( ; a >= 1; a-- ) {

        for ( int i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {
             printf("%d", b);
        }  
        b++; 
        printf("\n");
    }      
}
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
1111
222
33
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int a=4; a<=1; a--)
```

it will get out of the loop in the first iteration as a=4 and 4 is not less then 1

one of the way to print this is....

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;

    for (a=1; a<=4; a++) 
    {
        for (b=4; b<=1; b--) {
        printf("%d", a);
        }
    } 
    printf("\n");
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```